# Running python code on server

Tags: python, server

I'm building a website with some backprocessing with python. I want to know how to execute my python code from the server ?

There is no direct link between my HTML pages and my python code.

Let's say I want to do an addition with python in the server, how can I do that ?

Thanks so much in advence :)

Comment: By running the code from your server and demonizing it?

Comment: You can use python web frameworks like django, flask, pyramid for building websites.

Comment: smells like homework

Answer (score 0):

is your server is linux or windows?

for linux: you can add a script to run your script on runlevel 3 or 5
write a script put it under /etc/init.d/ folder then link your script /etc/rc3.d or /etc/rc5.d to be start

Comment: I'm not used to this stuff... I didn't understand... sorry :D
Do you have a tuto to recommand ? (I already googled it)

Comment: Is that php? If it is, search for php python integration then You can call from php

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try this :)